# custom recycler view show in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, android-recyclerview

Is there anyway that I can customize my recycler view (or list view or something else) to show not like a horizontal or vertical list but like a circle.
I give you an example of what do I want it to look like.

Example :

[image: example]

I want it to be generic so I can't just design it and put buttons in it.

Is there anyway I can do this with or without Recycler view or with something else? and how?

thank you.

Comment: if you want to use the recycler view for this, you have to create a custom layout manager for the recycler view. have a look at this [medium blog](https://medium.com/android-development-by-danylo/10-steps-to-create-a-custom-layoutmanager-2f30ab2f979d). It explains how to create a custom layout manager.